# Zorba PHP extension causes PHP to crash

Tags: php, zorba

I'm using a [tutorial](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/documentation/2.7.0/zorba/php_windows_tutorial) to try out the Zorba XQuery processor on my Windows 7 system, but when I add this line to my **php.ini**;

```
extension = zorba_api.dll
```

and try to start PHP, it throws this error;

[image]

I copied **zorba_api.dll** from **C:\Program Files\Zorba XQuery Processor 2.7.0\share\php** to the **C:\Program Files\PHP\ext** folder. Do I need to copy any more files?

Answer (score 0):

This error might mean that the zorba extension has been compiler with a different visual studio version than the one that compiled PHP.
Would it be possible to have pecl.net to compile the zorba extension?